# Angular - displaying custom component instead of Mat Dialog Component

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Is there a way to display own custom component using Mat Dialog from Angular Material Library, but completely "hiding" Mat Dialog and displaying **only** custom component on its place? I managed to "match" both, but there still are some artifacts like [background might still be visible etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhevT.png).

I tried to hide that somehow using CSS but it's not working as I want

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A "normal" Material Dialog can be look like you want!

[Here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/dialog/overview), the first example show this.

**DIALOG(!) HTML**

```
<h1>Hi {{data.name}}</h1>
<div>
  <label id="favorite-animal">What's your favorite animal?</label>
  <input for="favorite-animal" [(ngModel)]="data.animal" placeholder="Enter your name">
</div>
<div>
  <button (click)="dialogRef.close(data.animal)">OK</button>
  <button (click)="dialogRef.close()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

**DIGALOG SCSS**

```
:host {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 8px 16px 16px;
}

input {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

button + button {
  margin-left: 8px;
}
```

**COMPONENT WHICH CALL THE DIALOG HTML**

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <label id="dialog-user-name">What's your name?</label>
    <input for="dialog-user-name" [(ngModel)]="name">
  </li>
  <li>
    <button (click)="openDialog()">Pick one</button>
  </li>
  <li *ngIf="animal">
    You chose: <em>{{animal}}</em>
  </li>
</ol>
```

**AND THE COMPONENTS CODE**

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {Dialog, DialogRef, DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/cdk/dialog';

export interface DialogData {
  animal: string;
  name: string;
}

/**
 * @title CDK Dialog Overview
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'cdk-dialog-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'cdk-dialog-overview-example.html',
})
export class CdkDialogOverviewExample {
  animal: string | undefined;
  name: string;

  constructor(public dialog: Dialog) {}

  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open<string>(CdkDialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: {name: this.name, animal: this.animal},
    });

    dialogRef.closed.subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      this.animal = result;
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'cdk-dialog-overview-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'cdk-dialog-overview-example-dialog.html',
  styleUrls: ['cdk-dialog-overview-example-dialog.css'],
})
export class CdkDialogOverviewExampleDialog {
  constructor(public dialogRef: DialogRef<string>, @Inject(DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {}
}
```

Looks like:

[image]

#### Note

Instead of the Dialogs *HTML* you can add your own component in this place. I use this always and it works as well ;-)